# Symfony organisation

Tags: php, symfony, structure, symfony4

I am a on new project using **symfony4**, and as I'm not very experienced with the model structure, I think I went the wrong way but can't figure out how to fix it in a clean way.

I have different Controller:

- **SmugmugController** (I use it to interact with an online api,  getting all my information about pictures & stuff, and also uploading pictures from url, with an action or a function).
- **PrestaController** (I use it to interact with the DB, getting my next events, showing a list of events, and also some function to retrieve data.
- **DropBoxController** (this one is tricky, because i need to be able to call some actions, and also a lot of function in the others controllers. The main action in dropbox get data in the presta DB (**PrestaController**), upload pictures (**SmugmugController**), update the user DB (**UserController**)).

I have some more but not really relevant as its simple actions.

-> I guess that if I need to call that much other controllers, that's not the right way to do it?

-> Or do I just define my controllers as a service ?

Comment: Instead of having a bunch of logic in your controllers, create services for handling the business logic and just let the controller call the services it needs. Then you can call the same services from any controller. Let the controller only control  the request , like get data from the request, call the correct services and then return the appropriate result. In my opinion, if a controller needs to call another controller to get work done, you've probably put too much logic into your controllers (of course there are exceptions, but, in my opinion,  they are rare).

Comment: I agree. Your controllers should just be thought of as endpoints for the http/api requests from your users. Have the business logic you want to reuse in models/services that you can call from either controller.

Comment: Read more about thin controllers here https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html

Comment: Ok I will move it all to a service then ! I also need a lot of parameter from the newly soon created service (oauth user token/secret, consumer key... As it is only set once at the project startup I wanted to store it service.yaml, do I keep it there adding an access to those information to the service, or move the data directly to the service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used services as suggested, and extended one service from the other one, thanks.